# Why mysql driver is not currently installed Error is coming on Local Server?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo

I have a `php` project developed using `zend framework`, when i hosted to my local server(CentOS) i got the 
below error:

```
The mysql driver is not currently installed
```

I have installed and **enabled pdo_mysql on php.ini**, but it is not effected my phpinfo.
Phpinfo only show **pdo_sqlite** not see pdo_mysql.

Another issue in my machine is `phpinfo` shows `PHP version 5.2.8` and from terminal it shows PHP 5.1.6. Are there two php version running my machine?
Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: do a file search for `php.exe` and see what you'll find

Comment: no exe file , it is a linux machine CentOs

Comment: Oops, sorry.. check in your `httpd.conf` for `PHPIniDir` you'll see the version used by apache

Answer (score 2):

Check your phpinfo() output for the location of the php.ini file used and make sure to adapt that file. It's perfectly possible to have multiple versions of php running on a single computer.

It will show near the top of the output as (here's mine):

```
 Loaded Configuration File      /etc/php5/apache2filter/php.ini
```

that would be the location of the file you need to edit to affect your webserver instance php behaviour.

make sure to `extension=php_pdo_mysql.so` in it to load the mysql pdo driver

finally also make sure that `extension_dir` points to the directory where your libraries are found, using an absolute path; you can find that in phpinfo() under **Core** (and in your php.ini when you want to adapt it obviously)